# duplicity restore went wrong

Tags: 17.04, testdisk, duplicity, rstudio

Using --force in a duplicity restore experiment, I accidentally made duplicity delete numerous folders. Yes, it is possible to destroy data with backup software.

Testdisk not R-studio are able to restore any of the deleted files. Most likely because I recreated the main foldernames, before I started recovery.

Any ideas?

These are the steps I took:

**1) locating my testfile: test.txt**

```
duplicity list-current-files file:///media/myusername/external_HDD/backup_old_laptop >> /media/myusername/DATA/someList.txt
```

So far so good

**2A) restoring the test fileE**

```
duplicity -t 3D -v9 --file-to-restore media/DATA/09_TEST/test.txt file:///media/myusername/external_HDD/backup_old_laptop /media/myusername/DATA/09_TEST_RESTORED
```

Bummer, all I got was an empty file called 09_TEST_RESTORED

**2B) using the --force and removed 09_TEST/test.txt**

```
duplicity -t 3D -v9 --force --file-to-restore media/DATA/09_TEST/test.txt file:///media/mysuername/external_HDD/backup_old_laptop /media/myusername/DATA/
```

**MAYDAY:** This command structurally deletes files & folders on my current Laptop!!

**3) damage control**
I killed my terminal and I killed Nautillus file explorer

**4A) repair action one**
Unfortunately I manually recreated the lost top directories by hand.

**4B) repair action two**
I ran testdisk:

```
testdisk /dev/sda3
```

I selected the red folders and pressed `C to copy the selected files`

This restored my folders, but they are empty and by default I have now write access to these folders.

**5) doublecheck the partion**
fsck does not report abnormalities

```
sudo fsck.ext4 -p -b -f 32768 -B 4096 /dev/sda3
```

So now I have new folders, like before, but they are empty.

**6) r-studion demo**
A scan with R-studio Demo does not show the deleted files after scanning.

**7) Questioning the remains of the day:** 
Is it possible to drill down to deleted folders I recreated with the same name?

Comment: Since you have a backup, why not restore it?  You can use deja-dup or the context menu in nautilus to avoid command-line issues.  In nautilus you can right-click in your empty folder and select "restore missing files".

Comment: extundelete looks for files references at the inode level. and restores complete files that it finds

Comment: @Organic Marble: Thank you. Yes I do have a backup... one from an older different machine... which I wanted to merge onto my new machine, all ready in use and without decent backup

Comment: @Ravery: Thank you. I will explore extundelete.

Comment: Extundelete is unable to recover as well... due to 'reallocated space'.